# Deleting files in subfolders older than x days

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete all files in subfolders of a given folder without deleting the subfolders themselves. I have tried various examples but they are not doing what I expect.

The basic structure of the file tree I am trying to negotiate is:

```
C:\Backups\Subfolder1
C:\Backups\Subfolder2
C:\Backups\Subfolder3
```

and I am using the following code:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$path  = "C:\Backups"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force |
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } |
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

I am finding that the files in the subdirectories are being ignored despite the `-Recurse` flag being used, although any files in the C:\Backups directory are included. If I remove the `!$_.PSIsContainer` clause the file in the subfolder is included but so are all of the directories.

Can anyone show me how to include the files in the subfolder while still ignoring the subfolders themselves?

Comment: I don't see an error in your code, this should work... Are you aware that you are using the `-WhatIf` flag and no files get actual deleted?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. At this stage I am only verifying which files are being deleted.

Comment: After changing the lt to a gt because I couldn't recreate with a file created over two weeks ago, it works for me as well `What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Backups\Subfolder1\Test.txt".`

Comment: @BenH `$f = New-Item 'C:\path\to\file' -Type File; $f.CreationTime = $f.CreationTime.AddDays(-21)`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks, I guess I should have phrased it more precisely as I was too lazy to modify the creationtime rather than change one letter. Hopefully the intention that the script works as intended was still clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using powershell 3.0 you can simply use the `-File` switch:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$path = "C:\Backups"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Recurse | where { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Backups -Directory:$false -Recurse
$files | ForEach-Object -Process {
  if($_.CreationTime -lt $limit)
  {
    Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force
  }  
}
```

The `-Directory:$False` parameter means you don't have to worry about deleting any directories because they won't be included in the array.

Comment: The -Directory:$False parameter means you don't have to worry about deleting any directories because they wont be included in the array.

Comment: You should add that as an edit to your answer as comments are not always read and not guaranteed to be preserved. Also your answer might be more useful with a little more explanation.

Comment: I'm having no luck with this approach either, directories are still included. Further research has however lead me to this: 'code' $files2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Attributes !D and this does achieve my goal of ignoring directories.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me. Are you on an older version of powershell?

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$path  = "C:\Users\nathan.cooper\Documents"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | 
  where { (! $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit) } |
  Remove-Item -whatif
```